# pyqtgraph QGraphicsWidget import error

Tags: python, import, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to make a program using `PyQt5` and `pyqtgraph`, however, I keep running into this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'QGraphWidget'

I used `QtDesigner` to make a form and promoted a `QGraphicsWidget`. I know I did it correctly (I've done it at least 10 times to try and resolve the issue), but the error persists.

I'm using `Windows 7`, `Anaconda`, and `PyCharm`, but I tried running the code in other environments and still got the error.

Comment: You could show an image of how you promoted it. I want to see the attributes that you have placed as the base class name, the header file, etc.

Comment: `QGraphicsWidget` or `QGraphWidget`?

Comment: I followed the pyqtgraph documentation while I was promoting, it's here if anyone wants it:

[documentation](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/how_to_use.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation it implies that the promoted name can be anything, however, this seems to be untrue (at least at the moment).

> Under “Promoted class name”, enter the class name you wish to use (“PlotWidget”, “GraphicsLayoutWidget”, **etc**).

After re-doing my QGraphicsWidget for the 6th time, I decided to name it one of the example names in the tutorial, which seems to have solved the problem.

In other words name your widget and promoted widget "PlotWidget", "ImageView", "GraphicsLayoutView", or "GraphicsView". (Please keep in mind I have only tested "PlotWidget".)